# Restricting user access in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am working on asp.net application. I want only logged in users to access the Game page. When the users log in, the id and pass are authenticated from the SQL then they are logged in. and I want the logged in users to have an access to Games.aspx.

Here is the login code,

```
  public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    //"Data Source=MUNIZA\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LD_Server;Integrated Security=True";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbInfo.Enabled = false;
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBoolean(Session["sIsAuthenticated"] ?? false); }
        set { Session["sIsAuthenticated"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    string strcon = "Data Source=MUNIZA\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LD_Server;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);



        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spStudentProfile", con);

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("RegNo", TextBox2.Text);

        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("Password", TextBox1.Text);


        com.Parameters.Add(p1);

        com.Parameters.Add(p2);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();

        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            IsAuthenticated = true;
            rd.Read();

            Response.Redirect("~/Games.aspx");

        }



        else
        {
            IsAuthenticated = false;
            lbInfo.Enabled = true;
            lbInfo.Text = "Invalid username or password.";


        }
    }
```

It is the login code on every page,

```
                     <% 
  string url = "~/Login.aspx", text = "Log in";
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["sIsAuthenticated"] ?? false))
 { url = "~/Home.aspx"; text = "Log out"; }
  %>
  <a href="<%: ResolveUrl(url) %>"><%: text %></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but you do not seem to actually have a question, no? Please clarify what your exact problem is with this code

Comment: I just want the logged in users to be able to access certain page. And log in is done when authenticated from sql db.

Comment: Do you get any error messages, were is the problem located? Can the users login? Are re-directed to the wrong page? The more information you supply the easier it will be for the SO experts to give a good answer

Comment: Its just the code that is allowing users to log in. I want the session to be maintained when the users log in and only when they are logged in they can access.